# Folder based SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

I am new to SharePoint 2016 and am being asked to make a approval process at the folder level. Each folder has to follow a different workflow, because they are managed by different teams. 
Once the workflow is set, it does't work as the similar for the list. 
I mean, the new uploaded documents don't follow any approval path: no assigned tasks, no confirmation email. Just directly published. 
Does anyone know how to fix this issue? 
Are there issue in working in folders in SharePoint? 
Thanks.